# Jenkins - How is it possible that bat console works inside the sshagent plugin but the sh console does not?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Does anybody know why:

```
…
steps 
{
    script 
    {   
        sshagent(credentials: ['jenk']) 
        {
            sh "git remote show …"  //This does not work !
            bat "git remote show …" //This works ??  
        }
    }
}
...
```

The 'jenk' credentials are managed via Jenkins->credentials->System->global credentials

EDIT:
Sorry forgot the error msg:

```
    Host key verification failed
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Comment: "This does not work" Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what happens. Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins was configured using CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW (i686 Cygwin) for the sh commands.

After all this commands cleared everything:

```
if (isUnix()) 
{
    echo  "Jenkins runs on Linux"                     
}
else 
{
    echo  "Jenkins runs on Windows"
}

echo "show shell kernel version (uname -a) : "
def res = sh (script: "uname -a", returnStdout: true)
echo "${res}" //=>CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW...

res2 = sh (script: "ls -al ~/.ssh", returnStdout: true)
echo "${res2}"
```

So the solution to the problem above is therefore adding the ssh-keys to cygwin

If you need your credentials you could do this:
https://codurance.com/2019/05/30/accessing-and-dumping-jenkins-credentials/